# Join all except last x in list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have a list and want to join all except the last 2 entries
i.e.

```
x = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
print ', '.join(x[from 0 until -3])
```

Output would then be `1, 2`. How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use [slicing](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/introduction.html#lists)

```
>>> x = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
>>> print ', '.join(x[:-2])
1, 2
```