# Is there a simpler function or one liner to check if folder exists if not create it and paste a specific file into it?

Tags: python

I am aiming to create a function that does the following:

- Declare a path with a file, not just a folder. e.g. `'C:/Users/Lampard/Desktop/Folder1/File.py'`
- Create a folder in same folder as the declared file path - Calling it 'Archive'
- Cut the file and paste it into the new folder just created.
- If the folder 'Archive' already exists - then simply cut and paste the file into there

I have spent approx. 15-20min going through these:

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/directory

[Join all except last x in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30688187/join-all-except-last-x-in-list)

https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#operators

And here is what I got to:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path, PurePath
from shutil import copy

#This path will change every time - just trying to get function right first 
path = 'C:/Users/Lampard/Desktop/Folder1/File.py'

#Used to allow suffix function
p = PurePath(path)

#Check if directory is a file not a folder
if not p.suffix:
    print("Not an extension")

#If it is a file
else:
    #Create new folder before last file
    #Change working directory
    split = path.split('/')
    new_directory = '/'.join(split[:-1])
    apply_new_directory = os.chdir(new_directory)
    #If folder does not exist create it
    try:
        os.mkdir('Archive')#Create new folder
    #If not, continue process to copy file and paste it into Archive
    except FileExistsError:
        copy(path, new_directory + '/Archive/' + split[-1])
```

Is this code okay? - does anyone know a simpler method?

Comment: If you just want to know if this is the *recommended* way, then please use [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) Use Stack Overflow only if you have any problem regarding the code

Answer (score 0):

Locate folder/file in path

```
print [name for name in os.listdir(".") if os.path.isdir(name)]
```

Create path

```
    import os

# define the name of the directory to be created
path = "/tmp/year"

try:
    os.mkdir(path)
except OSError:
    print ("Creation of the directory %s failed" % path)
else:
    print ("Successfully created the directory %s " % path)
```

To move and cut files you can use [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html) library

Answer (score 0):

As you're already using `pathlib`, there's no need to use `shutil`:

```
from pathlib import Path
path = 'C:/Users/Lampard/Desktop/Folder1/File.py' # or whatever
p = Path(path)
target = Path(p.with_name('Archive')) # replace the filename with 'Archive'
target.mkdir()                        # create target directory
p.rename(target.joinpath(p.name))     # move the file to the target directory
```

Feel free to add appriopriate try…except statements to handle any errors.

**Update:** you might find this version more readable:

```
target = p.parent / 'Archive'
target.mkdir()
p.rename(target / p.name)
```

This is an example of overloading `/` operator.

Comment: where is `p.with_name` come from?

Comment: `p` is an object of class `Path`, `with_name` is a method in this class - see https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.with_name

Comment: Oh, and you may also want to read this tutorial: https://realpython.com/python-pathlib/